# Websphere MQ as txn coordinator:- MQ.begin() fails after mq backout due to db2 not able to start xa

Tags: java, db2, ibm-mq, xa

```
Environment details:-
```

1. Websphere MQ:- 7.5.0.2 on Redhat Linux 6.4
2. IBM DB2:- 10.1.0.2 on Redhat Linux 6.4
3. Java 1.7
4. Websphere MQ classes for Java
5. MQ as trasnaction coordinator

---

```
Scenario:-
```

All the below steps performed on the same thread. DB connection is opened and kept open for all the UoW being done on the thread.

1. qm.begin
2. get message and process the message
3. qm.commit
4. qm.begin
5. get message and exception was thrown during message processing
6. qm.backout
7. qm.begin ( **this fails with MQJE001:Completion Code '2', Reason '2009'.**)

The error log of the queue manager shows

**AMQ7605: The XA resource manager "dbname" has returned an unexpected return code -6, when called for xa_start**

Does anyone know what went wrong?

---

If we repeat the steps from above scenario with closing db connection after each commit or rollback, everything works fine. However this means we have to open and close connection per transaction which could affect the performance.

Does this mean after rollback of transaction, the connection used in the uow which got backed out can't be reused? Or we are missing something?

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: Could anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

The AMQ7605 error you pasted in shows return code -6. This is an XA return code, the details of which can be found in the XA specification:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009680699/toc.pdf

On page 24 you'll find the definition of -6:

#define XAER_PROTO -6 /∗ routine invoked in an improper context ∗/

In this instance, it means that when MQ (the transaction manager) called xa_open on the database (the resource manager), the database refused the attempt stating that it was in violation of the XA protocol.

I'd guess that either MQ isn't doing the right thing, or the database is invalidly complaining about the attempt. Either way I'd suggest opening a PMR with IBM MQ to look into the issue for you and give a formal response.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response.  Yes we have approached IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by setting DB2XADataSource's supportsAsynchronousXARollback flag to true.

```
final DB2XADataSource dataSource = new DB2XADataSource();
dataSource.setsupportsAsynchronousXARollback(DB2BaseDataSource.YES);
...
...
```

Hope this helps others too.